# Debug Installation Of ActiveX Control in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, installation, activex, cab

I have an ActiveX control that runs on a website, where the old version installed fine.  Of course it runs and installs perfectly on the development computer.  The new version is versioned with a new name and a completely new CLSID.   The new version brings up the installation dialog in Vista in Internet Explorer 8 (with the correct Digital Signature, etc) however nothing things to happen upon install.  How can I determine exactly what happened after clicking Install (the control is not in the Objects directory, however the old Control is).  I remember when initially creating this control that there was a log where there was details about the failed installs, however, for the life of me I cannot remember where that was or find it on the destination computer.  This new version installs fine on some computers, but fails to install on some computers (it is not specific to Vista, it installs fine on some Vista machines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that Visual Basic components built in 64 bit windows silently fail to run on 32 bit operating systems (Vista, XP, Windows 7).  Don't know whether it is the VB compiler, the Cab generator, or signtool, but if you build it on 64bit, it will run fine in a 64bit environment but fail to install with no messages in a 32 bit environment.  Hopefully this will help someone in the future.  Still looking for the log for failed ActiveX installs, however.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen due to ActiveX being inactive. You can try by creating window which will try to Install ActiveX. I am sure it will work as APPLET OR OBJECT require to activate window. It can not be launched from hidden div or other tag.